# Jbpm 5 and Seam 3 integration

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management, seam2, seam3

Me and 14 collegues are taking the Engeneering Software Project course that takes 12 weeks from now.
The main propose in the project is to migrate the technologies between versions of an already made project.

The goal is to migrate from Seam 2.2 and Jbpm3 to Seam 3 and Jbpm5. Searching on the web we
found that there is no integration between them, so we don't really know how to continue. Also we have no experience developing with Java EE, Seam or Jbpm.

So the questions are,

- Did you ever tried to integrate Seam3 and Jbpm5? Is there any information on the web about it that didn't find? Will it be possible to do in 12 weeks for 14 developers with no experience in the subject?
- In case it will be impossible, is it possible to integrate Jbpm5 and an earlier version of Seam? Or Jbpm 4.3 with Seam3?
- Are the Jbpm5 advantages so important that we may include it in the migration? Or Jbpm 4.3 is a good goal?

We would greatly appreciate if you send as some suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Did you ever tried to integrate Seam3 and Jbpm5? Is there any information on the web about it that didn't find? Will it be possible to do in 12 weeks for 14 developers with no experience in the subject?

*A:* There have been no efforts yet to integrate Seam3 and jBPM 5. If I remember correctly, Seam2 pageflow is based on jpdl, which only jBPM 3 and 4 can read. jBPM 5 can *not* read jpdl. Whether or not it would be possible for 14 dev's to do it in 12 weeks depends on the level of the 14 developers. Given that none of the dev's have experience in Seam or jBPM, I don't think it will be possible.

---

**Q:** In case it will be impossible, is it possible to integrate Jbpm5 and an earlier version of Seam? Or Jbpm 4.3 with Seam3?

*A:* Integrating jBPM 4.3 with Seam 3 *might* be possible. But I'm not even sure the pageflow feature exists in Seam 3: there are some posts about it dating from 2010, but I'm not sure it was created in Seam 3.

---

**Q:** Are the Jbpm5 advantages so important that we may include it in the migration? Or Jbpm 4.3 is a good goal?

*A*: jBPM 5 has lots of advantages over jBPM 3, the most important ones being BPMN2 support and seamless integration with the rest of the Drools project. However, neither of those have to do with Seam integration.

In short, you're better off looking for another project for your class, IMHO.